# How to Manage Spammers on Facebook Group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I'm the admin of a few Facebook groups and I would like to know how I could do the following:

I would like to know how I could search the current and pending members in the group to see if their name matches with names on a text file of blacklisted members that I have?

There is no way to do this with Facebook itself unless there are ways with Developer access?

It is also impossible to see all the members easily as they have no list mode, only large thumbnails are shown next to each name which makes it difficult to try to copy and paste the names to another text file.

Comment: Are you comfortable with any kind of programming? I can suggest ways using the developer console.

Comment: I'm not really a coder but can copy and paste etc. I might be able to use it, how would it work? 

EDIT: I have now created a Facebook developer account, what should I do now?

Comment: Please visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer .
This lets you send requests to the API and get results. What I think you need is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/members .

Comment: In the explorer, after v2.8/ write you group id (which is usually the name of the group that appears in the URL) followed by /members. This will return the list of members in JSON format. Which will be pretty easy to parse and copy paste to make a list out of.

Comment: OK thanks I will take a look at this now and come back here with an update on how I go.

Comment: I think I know how to do this but when I run it I get this message:

"message": "An access token is required to request this resource.", - I will try now to create an access token although I'm not sure the correct way for this but I will give it a try now....

Comment: You can add ?limit=10000 (or a large enough number depending on you group) to see all the members in one go, instead of having to click next every time. Your final url will be /v2.8/1234345566/members?limit=10000.
Replace 1234345566 with appropriate group id.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: To get the appropriate access token, Get Token > Get User Access Token. Make sure "user managed groups is selected" and then click Get Access token. Once this is done, try to send the request again.

Comment: Im having a problem finding the right place to start with "Get Token > Get User Access Token. " is there an url I can find this part?

Comment: I think I found it

Comment: I have got it to work thanks, now I will try to figure out how to get a nice simple list of the names from this....?

Comment: So I was able to get a maxium of 3000 members per page or 1000 if I limit to search by name like :xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/members/?fields=name&limit=1000

. That is OK. The problem is it also lists some code and other details that are not needed like: 

`{
      "name": "John Doe",
      "id": "2072459XXXXX"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob Doe",
      "id": "87155XXXX"
    },
    {
  `
how I could I make a text list of just the names?

Comment: also I would like to get a list of Pending members. I see there is a "member_request_count" but that only lists the number. maybe a status readout or something might work?

Comment: I'm also having a problem trying to copy the page content, every time I try to copy the data so I can paste it into a text file it crashes. Is there some export feature or something?

Comment: I had to limit the search to 500 otherwise it would crash when copying the data. I then pasted it into Dreamweaver CS6 in code view, I was able to clean up the code with a search and replace so I could have 2 columns, 1 for the ID and another for the name. I could then just turn those names into a clean list. The problem is Dreamweaver does not allow code view commands to be saved so it would be tedious to do this for 10,000 plus members. So now I'm going to try to see if I can make a search and replace macro in Word. If not I will try to find another program to do this.

Comment: .... It would also be nice to know how to export the data from the dev console so i don't have to copy and paste 500 entries at a time?

Comment: I was able to clean up the file in word using a macro. I wanted to turn this: '{
      "name": "Joe Blogs",
      "id": "1457898XXXX0"
    },' 
into:

'      <tr><td>Joe Blogs</td><td>
      1457898XXXX0</td></tr>
'

now I can turn that into an html table and then delete the ID column if I want. I would like to know an easier way to export the names from the Dev console though?

Comment: OK I I was able to export the data at 3000 records at a time by clicking the debug button and copy it to word then run the macro to clean up the data. then I would open that up in Dreamweaver and put it into a table. Then I would delete the ID column, then I would preview it in a browser then I would copy it all into a text file and there is how I now have a clean file of all my members. Its not the fastest procedure but it works for now. I would like to know how I can find the pending members as well. thanks.